# Create a view to display minor or unpublished docs

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

I need to create a view in a document library to display all the minor versions. I did not see a column for filter to set this up. any idea.

I'm using SharePoint in Office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are some options to achieve this, but none is simple:

1. Using UI. This solution is not pretty and could result poor performance, but it could work. In your view make filter similar to this:

   Version CONTAINS ".1" or
   Version CONTAINS ".2" or
   ......
   Version CONTAINS ".9"
2. **RECOMMENDED** Using code (PowerShell, Server Side API or CSOM). You can set your CAML query of the view programmatically. Note: if you do this, you should not modify this view using UI, because UI will overwrite your view settings. In CAML you can filter using `_Level` [column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilelevel.aspx). You can filter items that is not published, to get minor versions.

> ```
> <Where>
>       <Neq>
>           <FieldRef Name='_Level' />
>           <Value Type='Integer'>2</Value>
>       </Neq>
> </Where>
> ```

You can check how to do modify view in [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/22/use-powershell-to-manage-lists-views-and-items-in-sharepoint.aspx) article.

Comment: This setup gives all the major or published version. I need to only display minor or unpublished versions.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a calculated column with formula `=IF((Version-INT(Version))<>0,"Draft","Published")` and use the column in a view as filter.

For detailed explanation you can visit [this](https://blog.binarybits.net/programming/sharepoint/view-unpublished-pages-or-draft-pages-or-published-pages-in-sharepoint/) article.